# File can't be parsed because java can't find it

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse an xml file and so far this is what I've written.

```
public class XMLTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    File xmlFile = new File("D:\\workspace\\sudoku baby\\sudoku.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
}
```

It keeps spitting out the file not found exception, like so

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\workspace\sudoku baby\sudoku.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:155)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:110)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:184)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:654)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:150)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:860)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:246)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:206)
at testingXML.XMLTest.main(XMLTest.java:14)
```

`
I've made absolute sure that it's the right file path, and after some testing it can find the file. The error happens when I try to parse it. I'm not sure what the problem here is exactly, if someone could point it out or help that would be great.

Comment: The path in the error message is different from the path in your source code. Make sure you're running the code you think you're running, by deleting all compiled code (.class files) for example

Comment: The error is in testingXML.Employees class as mentioned in the logs and not in XML Test class.

Comment: that output does not look like it came from that code... `"D:\\workspace\\sudoku baby\\sudoku.xml"` vs. `D:\Users\mtsoy\staff.xml`

Comment: There is a space in your path "sudoku baby" this tends to create problem number of times

Comment: @Shailesh Only in shell commands. Not in filenames inside applications.

Comment: @user207421 I don't disagree with you, but I have seen lot in decade, there was a time when window itself was not able to handle more than 8 character in folder name , I used to access "program files" as progra~1 , so bottom rule , if in doubt leave it out. that's why I didn't say certainly it creates problem, rather i said .......number of time :)

Comment: Some doubt the space, one could also question rights on D:. _Just test it by other paths._

Answer (score 0):

Please, try following code:

```
File xmlFile = new File(Paths.get("D:","workspace", "sudoku baby", "sudoku.xml").toString());
```